# Why doesn't my variable update when using pop() method?

Tags: python

I am learnng Python with Python Crash Course, and I am at the lists chapter.

I have a guest list, and I'm supposed to print a message for each one (no loops yet) in which I have to tell them they're not invited to an event using method pop().

```py
#I tried this :

removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest
print(apology)
print(apology)
print(apology)


#but I figured the variable needs to be updated for each print

#I tried re-adding the removed_guest variable for each print:


removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology)


#but this is where I made a mistake because the same thing happens (shouldn't removed guest list update with the newest last item in the list since I already popped that one out?

#at last I did this:

apology = 'you cannot come to dinner '
print(apology + guestlist.pop())
print(apology + guestlist.pop())
print(apology + guestlist.pop())

#this works but I'm curious as to why the apology variable doesn't get updated even though I updated remove_guest.
```

Comment: Recommended reading: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html It is really worth to spend some time to read it carefully if you are learning Python and your question is also mentioned there.

Answer (score 2):

Assignment statements (*x* = *y*) assign a value to *x* at the point they are executed; they do not define some kind of relationship that causes that action to be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

> this works but im curios as to why the apology variable doesnt get updated even tho i updated remove_guest

I believe that you mean here?

```
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology)
```

Lets say that we have guest A, B and C.
So your code will go like this. In first line, removed_guest will be set to C. Then you will say that apology is 'you cannot come to diner ' + 'C'. And you will print this. Then you will say that removed_guest is set to B. Then you will print apology. Then you will say that removed guest is A, an then you will print apology. But as you can see, apology was set only once, with guest C. But the content of apology is always 'you cannot come to diner ' + 'C'.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your query clearly, you are only updating removed_guest variable (and not apology variable) before each print command but are expecting apology to get updated as well.

In order to update apology, you need to update it before each print command :

```
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest
print(apology)
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing a variable gives you the previous value that was stored in it.

Accessing a varible *does not re-run the expression used to define it*. This would defy the whole point of a variable which is to remember a value without having to recompute it.

You might not have learned about functions yet; functions are what you are thinking of: a way to re-run the same expression on demand.

```
guestlist = ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz']

def apologize():
    return 'you cannot come to dinner ' + guestlist.pop()

print(apologize()) # you cannot come to dinner Baz
print(apologize()) # you cannot come to dinner Bar
print(apologize()) # you cannot come to dinner Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code block, you assigned the removed_guest variable with the specific removed_guest value. Variables are not pointers. When you assign to a variable you are binding the name to an object. From that point onwards you can refer to the object by using the name until that name is rebound. When you define a string it will create a reference to the particular string value in the memory.

```
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
#String is defined and saved in the memory 
apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest 
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology)
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not updating `apology` after every `pop`. The assignment of the variable apology is by value and not by reference for `removed_guest`. Hence the variable `apology` doesn't update on it's own even when you change `removed_guest`.
You can do `apology = 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest` after every pop and before printing.
Try something like this if you want to use functions:

```
def apology(guest):
    return 'you cannot come to dinner ' + removed_guest

removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology(removed_guest))
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology(removed_guest))
removed_guest = guestlist.pop()
print(apology(removed_guest))
```

Answer (score -1):

because it is a string, you should have done it like this if you want it to return argument specific value.

```
def apology(guest_name):
    return "you cannot come to dinner "+str(guest_name)

guestlist=["abc","def","jkl"]
print(apology(guestlist.pop()))
print(apology(guestlist.pop()))
print(apology(guestlist.pop()))
```

Comment: You need to use `guestlist.pop()` instead of `guestlist.pop`. Also, `apology` is not a function in the OP's code.